# How can I write test cases for instances in Haskell

Tags: haskell, testing, functional-programming, programming-languages

I have an instance of Num for a type I created called Vec:

```
instance Num Vec where
  (+) (Vec x) (Vec y) = Vec (zipWith (+) x y)
```

And I am trying to write a test case for it like I normally do. Normally, I test functions and not instances. I usually do it this way this way:

```
spec :: Spec
spec = do
  describe "(+)" $ do
    it "produces (Vec [2])" $
      Vec [1] + Vec [1] `shouldBe` Vec [2]
```

Since the code above doesn't produce any results, does this mean I'd have to create functions for (+) in order to test it? How can I do it for instances?

Comment: Your test case looks legit to me. What problems do you see with it?

Comment: I just tried out this code (filling in the gaps with what I assume you would have) with the `hspec` package and ran `hspec spec` and it seemed to work fine. What does the rest of the code look like?

Comment: When I run ```stack test``` I get a message: ```Test suite not yet implemented```

Comment: @Lexi: likely this is because your `.cabal` file has no testsuite defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question but it is too long for a comment.

It seems like `Vec` uses pointwise lifting of `Num`.

This corresponds to using `Applicative` lifting ([`Ap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap)) over [`ZipList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList):

```
{-# Language DerivingVia #-}

import Control.Applicative (ZipList(..))
import Data.Monoid         (Ap(..))

-- >> Vec [1] + Vec [1]
-- Vec [2]
newtype Vec = Vec [Int]
  deriving Num
  via Ap ZipList Int
```

You can also use [`deriving newtype IsList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:IsList) if you want to use list syntax for `Vec`.